# How to make a second onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I was wondering how to make an onClick, but make one that does an action on the second click.
OnSecondClick didn't work.

Thank you.

With onDBLClick you have to click fast, so please don't answer that.

Comment: Put a counter variable in the click handler.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a handler for double-click?

Comment: Hello, Barmar, I don't have any idea what a click handler is.

Comment: A click handler is the function that runs when you click on something. E.g. if you write `onclick="doSomething()"`, `doSomething` is the click handler.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean a double click ?

If so, use the ondblclick event

```
<element ondblclick="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

If you simply want to capture the second click, as Barmar suggested just keep track of the number of clicks and act on the second one

```
var clickCounter = 0;

object.onclick=function(){

 clickCounter++;

 if (clickCounter == 2)
 {
   //second click happened!!! - now reset counter
   clickCounter = 0;
 }
};
```

Comment: Oh, I already knew that, but onDBLClick only works if you double click fast. I'm very sorry I forgot to put that in the question.